# Salesforce Internal Error in Lightning with Gack Id 1033058303

Tags: lightning-aura-components, gack

I have added a lightning component using app builder.
Component renders properly in app builder, it also renders in classic(using lightning out) but as soon as I navigate to actual detail page it shows me following error.

> Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem
>   continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID
>   shown here and any other related details. An internal server error has
>   occurred

I checked logs no errors on apex controller side.

How to find error stack trace for such error for UI.

Answer (score 0):

Somethings' gone wrong deeper down in the system, and unfortunately the only people who can give you more information are Salesforce support. If you don't have premium and/or developer support your chances of getting any assistance are pretty slim.